# WriteLn Travando no Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tendo um problema onde ao passar pela função `write` o mesmo acaba travando dentro da função, e não retorna nada, tendo que fechar a aplicação e abrir de novo, abaixo o código para teste, basta criar um projeto e colar o código no FormCreate:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  F        : TextFile;
  mArquivo,s : String;
  i: integer;
begin
   {$i+}
   mArquivo :=  'C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\teste.txt';
   AssignFile(F,mArquivo);

   if FileExists(mArquivo) then
      DeleteFile(mArquivo);

   Rewrite(F,mArquivo);
   Append(F);

   for i := 0 to 10 do
   begin
      S := 'Text'+ IntToStr(i);
      Write(F,S);
   end;
   CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Comment: Amigo, não tenho o **Seatle**, e sim o **XE 7**, porém quais são os parâmetros solicitados pela função **ReWrite()**? Porque tentando reproduzir seu código, apenas passei a variável **F** na função **ReWrite** e tudo funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Agora que você falou, funcionou mesmo tirando o argumento que estava ali, para falar a verdade não tinha percebido esse campo e funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme comentado, basta remover o parâmetro **mArquivo** da função *ReWrite* e irá funcionar.

Answer (score 5):

Comentado o código encontrado.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  F        : TextFile;
  mArquivo,s : String;
  i: integer;
begin
   {$i+}
   mArquivo :=  'C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\teste.txt';
   AssignFile(F,mArquivo);

   // Se você vai usar o rewrite abaixo então não tem
   // sentido fazer isso aqui.   
   if FileExists(mArquivo) then
      DeleteFile(mArquivo);

   // O rewrite cria o arquivo e, caso ele exista, vai apaga-lo
   // e recriar um novo.

   Rewrite(F,mArquivo); // Erro

   // Append serve para você abrir um arquivo e adicionar novas linhas a  
   // a ele. Aqui é totalmente desnecessário. 
   Append(F);

   for i := 0 to 10 do
   begin
      S := 'Text'+ IntToStr(i);
      // Isso, claro, deveria ser WriteLn
      Write(F,S);
   end;
   CloseFile(F);
end;
```

Reescrevendo.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  F        : TextFile;
  mArquivo,s : String;
  i: integer;
begin
   {$i+}
   mArquivo :=  'C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\teste.txt';
   AssignFile(F,mArquivo);

   // Como a variavel F é um textFile então rewrite tem apenas um parametro
   Rewrite(F);

   for i := 0 to 10 do
   begin
      S := 'Text'+ IntToStr(i);
      WriteLn(F,S);
   end;
   CloseFile(F);
end;
```